# Anchor tag validation

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make an anchor tag cause both client and server validation. I have this code for now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

              $('div#imgEmailVerifyLoader').hide();

              $('a#btn_SubmitContactMessage').click(function () 
              {
                  if (Page_ClientValidate()) // this will trigger all validators on page  
                  {
                      $('div#imgEmailVerifyLoader').show('slow');
                      window.Form_OnMasterPage.submit();
                      return true;
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                      return false;
                  }

              });

          });  

<a id="btn_SubmitContactMessage" href="Contact.aspx"  onclick="Validate();" runat="server">SUBMIT</a>
```

This performs client validation properly and shows the error message. I have validation controls for each of the textboxes on the page. I also added a server click event handler in code behind for this:

```
 btn_SubmitContactMessage.ServerClick +=new EventHandler(btn_SubmitContactMessage_ServerClick);


        }

        protected void btn_SubmitContactMessage_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsValid)
            {

                RequiredFieldValidator4.ErrorMessage = "show";
                return;
            }
        }
```

But when I try to test it by turning off javascript the link(submit) does not postback. Why is that happening?

Now, how do I make sure that validation is being done on the server side to after postback.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's because of the 'onclick=validate()'. Instead of doing that you should register that event inside of '$(document).ready(function ()' like you've got your other JavaScript. That way if JavaScript is not available the form is submitted normally and your server side validation kicks in.